# 'int' object has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python

I have a problem with making my player move. I used a youtube tutorial to make a pixelart zelda-like game and when i want to move my character the compiler outputs an error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'y'
```

I don't know why this is occurring, because I have included all the lines of code that were shown in the tutorial.

Here is my player code:

```
import pygame
from settings import *

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\bekie\Desktop\projekt\graphics\test\player.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)

        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.speed = (5,)

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.direction.y = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.direction.y = 1
        else:
            self.direction = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction = 0

    def move(self, speed):
        self.rect.center += self.direction * speed

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        self.move(self.speed)
```

and my level code:

```
from cmath import rect
import pygame
from settings import *
from tile import Tile
from player import Player
from debug import debug

class Level:
    def __init__(self):

        #tworzenie powierzchni wyświetlania
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

        #ustawienia grupy sprite'ów
        self.visible_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.obstacle_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        #stawianie sprite'ów
        self.create_map()

    def create_map(self):
        for row_index, row in enumerate(WORLD_MAP):
            for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
                x = col_index * TILESIZE
                y = row_index * TILESIZE
                if col == 'x':
                    Tile((x, y), [self.visible_sprites, self.obstacle_sprites])
                if col =='p':
                    self.player = Player((x, y), [self.visible_sprites])

    def run(self):
        #wygląd gry i update'y
        self.visible_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)
        self.visible_sprites.update()
        debug(self.player.direction)
```

and maybe it's important. My main function code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame, sys
from settings import *
from level import Level

class Game:
    def __init__(self):

        #ustawienia ogólne
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGTH))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Kroniki Antilii')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.level = Level()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill('black')
            self.level.run()
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

and create map code:

```
#ustawienia gry
WIDTH       = 1280
HEIGTH      = 720
FPS         = 60
TILESIZE  = 64

WORLD_MAP = [
    ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','x','x','x','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','x','x',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','x','x','x','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','x','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','x',],
    ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x',]
    ]
```

I want to make my character move properly. Maybe somewere there i make a little mistake or i must implement some funcion or else.

Answer (score 1):

In the `__init__` method, you define `self.direction` to be a Vector:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, groups):
        ...
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
```

But then in the `input()` function, `self.direction` can get reassigned to a plain integer:

```
    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        ...
        else:
            self.direction = 0
```

Once this assignment happens, `self.direction` is a plain integer and is no longer a Vector, so it indeed does not have a `.y` attribute.